# Where can I find a real architecture document on Wordpress?

Tags: documentation

I can only find some db schemas, what about all the rest of business logics in UML ?

Comment: What exactly are you after?  There are API documents and the codex.  What architecture type documents are you looking for - sequence diagrams?  Class diagrams?

Comment: *@asksuperuser* - These generally are not some the open-source WordPress community focuses on doing. Do you need these for your own use or because someone you are developing a system for has stated that having them is a requirement?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any besides michel fortin's WP text flow diagram from a few years ago:

http://michelf.com/weblog/2005/wordpress-text-flow-vs-markdown/

That said, there were recent talks about writing some kind of plugin dev's companion reference with the full flowchart of the WP hooks and API.

Answer (score 3):

It's not business logic in UML (which would benefit from some refactoring of core first, right?), just some workflow PDF: [Wordpress 3.0 Program Flow (PDF)](http://toolpress.de/tools/Toolpress_-_Wordpress-3.0-Program-Flow-0.2-2010-06-28.pdf) [Preview](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aR5G9DUj0pTsJ%3atoolpress.de/tools/Toolpress_-_Wordpress-3.0-Program-Flow-0.2-2010-06-28.pdf+wordpress+program+flow&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESij1Sg5Xi-QYoMggSTynSlto_A-X20Y9x0MGA410lYK8MdRagDjc1hZi4x3H-4_F_MUgigDVzXuPHvej5vot7EKoknL9TAxRQAGqR7KhSJc9iVleXAV1azwGxdTlhg0fUG_jvge&sig=AHIEtbRfDE1ci6n4EZaKyc0ut2gbqmdOeQ)