# Looking for WordPress System Diagrams

Tags: plugin-development, templates, core

I am looking for WordPress chart/diagram system design.

I found only the template hierarchy diagram, but it's only part of the system.

[image]
<sup>source: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Wordpress_Template_Hierarchy.png</sup>

Comment: Simply put WP is too large to be charted to the small details. Try to focus your question on which aspects precisely you are interested in.

Comment: in mvc model - chart: main routing, model, controller, view.

Comment: @Yosef WordPress isn't really built around MVC

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<sup>***More than an Answer, this is a research and a compilation. Database Description already in Damien answer.***</sup>

---

---

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=es&sclient=psy-ab&q=wordpress%20uml&oq=wordpress%20uml&gs_l=hp.3...1977.10094.0.10309.11.10.0.0.0.7.652.3269.3-2j3j2.7.0...0.0.u_0NaE2XdcI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=d08a809886b2f1d9&biw=1119&bih=591) reveals this in WordPress forums:

> [UML documentation of WordPress](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/uml-documentation-of-wordpress?replies=4#post-1980538)
>   As far as I know, that's all we have. If you want to write one, I'm sure it'd be welcomed :)
>   (***Ipstenu***, referring to the Database Description)

> [UML of WordPress MU?](http://mu.wordpress.org/forums/topic/16746)
>   There will likely never be UML diagrams of WordPress because it's not
>   an OO system. Some parts are OO-like, but overall it's whatever that
>   particular code contributor made work. There's no map, just code.
>
> And IMO, the point of UML is that it's done in the architecting phase.
>   A project like WordPress would be hard-pressed to have this since it's
>   a fluid integration of independent developers contributing to the
>   core.
>   *[...]*
>
> Welcome to open source.

---

---

Note: the Template Hierarchy of WikiMedia in the OP Question differs from the one in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview)
[image: Codex Template Hierarchy]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

But, [Chip Bennet](http://www.chipbennett.net/themes/template-hierarchy/) has an extended one :)
[image: Chip Bennet Template Hierarchy]

---

---

I thought this Question was a duplicate of the following (but mods said it's not):
[Where can I find a real architecture document on Wordpress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/2938/12615)

In it, Mike Schinkel states:

> These generally are not some the open-source WordPress community focuses on doing.

One answer points to an [old article](http://michelf.com/weblog/2005/wordpress-text-flow-vs-markdown/) with this diagram:
[image: wordpress-text-flow-vs-markdown]

And the other to this [Wordpress 3.0 Program Flow (PDF)](http://toolpress.de/tools/Toolpress_-_Wordpress-3.0-Program-Flow-0.2-2010-06-28.pdf)
[image: Wordpress 3.0 Program Flow]

---

---

Rarst answer to this Question ( [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615) ) has a nice overview of WP_Query:
[image: WP_Query]

---

---

Another from Rarst on [core load](http://www.rarst.net/script/wordpress-core-load/):

[image]

---

---

And finally, a totally unrelated Question about performance ( [Refactoring Wordpress to improve memory performance](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/10463/12615) ), but with very nice graphs :)
[image: wp-performance]

Comment: Hats off to you @brasofilo thats a great research collection of reference diagrams.

Comment: I've added my less known diagram of core load.

Comment: If I could vote this up more than once, I would. :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for the **database schema**, [there is a version on the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description):
[image]

<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

The image you referenced in your post is the template hierarchy most commonly used by theme developers.

Comment: all system not only db

Comment: Hi @Yosef ... from your recent comment .... what you should look up is a LAMP stack diagram then